# Is there a way to select group by elements that are navigation properties in linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've a query, something like this

```
var ReportData = db.PY_History_TransactionTAB.AsEnumerable()
.Where(x => x.SystemCode == SysCode)
.GroupBy(x => new { x.EmployeeCode, x.EmployeeMaster.Emp_FullName});
```

For `x.EmployeeCode` selection of GroupBy member, it is easy to do :

```
ReportData.Select(x => new PY_History_TransactionTAB
{
   EmployeeCode = x.Key.EmployeeCode,
}
```

But, what if I want to select the next GroupBy member i.e. `x.EmployeeMaster.Emp_FullName`, How do I do this? so that I get it right at my strongly typed view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. So, if you have a navigation property, just place it in select() in this way :

```
ReportData.Select(x => new PY_History_TransactionTAB
{
   EmployeeCode = x.Key.EmployeeCode,
   EmployeeMaster = x.First().EmployeeMaster
}
```

Now you can have all properties of `EmployeeMaster` class as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReportData.Select(x => new 
{
   EmployeeCode = x.Key.EmployeeCode,
   EmployeeName = x.Key.Emp_FullName,
}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.